# Issue Running JAR file on Bluemix CF

Tags: java, jar, ibm-cloud

I tried to Run a JAR standalone app on Bluemix CF , and I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXX\Desktop\server>cf push BlynkServer -p server-0.16.4.jar
Creating app XXXXXServer in org XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com / space XXXXXSpace as XXXXXXXX@gmail.com...
OK

Creating route blynkserver.mybluemix.net...
OK

Binding blynkserver.mybluemix.net to BlynkServer...
OK

Uploading BlynkServer...
Uploading app files from: C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\unzipped-app927627203
Uploading 21.5M, 7024 files
Done uploading
OK

Starting app BlynkServer in org XXXXXX@gmail.com / space XXXXas XXXXXXX@gmail.com...
-----> Downloaded app package (12M)
    -----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v3.0-20160608-1450
-----> Retrieving IBM 1.8.0_20160428 JRE (ibm-java-jre-8.0-3.0-pxa6480sr3-20160428_01-cloud.tgz) ... (0.0s)
         Expanding JRE to .java ... (1.0s)
-----> Retrieving App Management 1.17.0_20160418-1204 (app-mgmt_v1.17-20160418-1204.zip) ... (0.0s)
         Expanding App Management to .app-management (0.1s)
-----> Liberty buildpack is done creating the droplet

-----> Uploading droplet (69M)

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 failing
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf logs BlynkServer --recent' for more information

C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\server>cf logs BlynkServer --recent
Connected, dumping recent logs for app BlynkServer in org XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com / space XXXXXXXXSpace as XXXXXXXXx@gmail.com...

2016-07-21T19:22:13.93+0300 [App/0]      OUT
2016-07-21T19:23:59.04+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.hardware.ssl.HardwareSSLServer.<init>(HardwareSSLServer.java:35)
2016-07-21T19:23:59.25+0300 [API/10]     OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"eaba3509e77f4178b8683f96b0d3027b", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469118239}
2016-07-21T19:24:52.52+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:66)
2016-07-21T19:25:44.83+0300 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"113504537eee41fdb710c7df6fb5a4d2", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469118344}
2016-07-21T19:30:10.55+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:58)
2016-07-21T19:30:10.59+0300 [App/0]      OUT
2016-07-21T19:40:50.91+0300 [DEA/5]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T19:54:05.74+0300 [App/0]      ERR     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No provider succeeded to generate a self-signed certificate. See debug log for the root cause.
2016-07-21T20:18:51.11+0300 [DEA/199]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T20:19:16.33+0300 [App/0]      OUT
2016-07-21T20:44:00.03+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.hardware.ssl.HardwareSSLServer.<init>(HardwareSSLServer.java:35)
2016-07-21T20:44:00.03+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:66)
2016-07-21T20:44:00.03+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:58)
2016-07-21T20:44:00.14+0300 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"9ef3f6b16bae468c9c3f8b3ecfdec5f1", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469123040}
2016-07-21T20:44:00.34+0300 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"9ef3f6b16bae468c9c3f8b3ecfdec5f1", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469123040}
2016-07-21T21:08:50.47+0300 [DEA/106]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:09:09.75+0300 [App/0]      ERR     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No provider succeeded to generate a self-signed certificate. See debug log for the root cause.
2016-07-21T21:09:09.75+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.utils.SslUtil.initSslContext(SslUtil.java:71)
2016-07-21T21:09:09.75+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.hardware.ssl.HardwareSSLServer.<init>(HardwareSSLServer.java:35)
2016-07-21T21:09:09.75+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:66)
2016-07-21T21:09:09.75+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:58)
2016-07-21T21:09:09.80+0300 [App/0]      OUT
2016-07-21T21:09:09.87+0300 [DEA/106]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-07-21T21:09:09.91+0300 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"0a06ec421d6c480794a36a4a9104fbce", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469124549}
2016-07-21T21:09:09.91+0300 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"0a06ec421d6c480794a36a4a9104fbce", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469124549}
2016-07-21T21:22:29.45+0300 [DEA/117]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:22:29.45+0300 [DEA/117]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:24:19.78+0300 [DEA/27]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:25:03.99+0300 [DEA/109]    OUT Removing crash for app with id 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:25:03.99+0300 [DEA/109]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:25:03.99+0300 [DEA/109]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:26:04.53+0300 [DEA/52]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:26:04.53+0300 [DEA/52]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:26:04.53+0300 [DEA/52]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:27:58.43+0300 [DEA/29]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:27:58.43+0300 [DEA/29]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:27:58.44+0300 [DEA/29]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:30:21.73+0300 [DEA/179]    OUT Removing crash for app with id 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:30:21.73+0300 [DEA/179]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:30:21.73+0300 [DEA/179]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:33:52.59+0300 [DEA/63]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:34:09.92+0300 [App/0]      ERR     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No provider succeeded to generate a self-signed certificate. See debug log for the root cause.
2016-07-21T21:34:09.92+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.utils.SslUtil.initSslContext(SslUtil.java:71)
2016-07-21T21:34:09.92+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.hardware.ssl.HardwareSSLServer.<init>(HardwareSSLServer.java:35)
2016-07-21T21:34:09.92+0300 [App/0]      ERR    at cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:66)
2016-07-21T21:34:09.95+0300 [App/0]      OUT
2016-07-21T21:34:10.16+0300 [DEA/63]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-07-21T21:34:10.22+0300 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"e5c04306743b421eaa0e974472d9f109", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469126050}
2016-07-21T21:34:10.22+0300 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc", "version"=>"314d1913-6bfe-4cd1-8b37-a7c6c60cce20", "instance"=>"e5c04306743b421eaa0e974472d9f109", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469126050}
2016-07-21T21:34:35.30+0300 [DEA/1]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:34:35.30+0300 [DEA/1]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:34:35.31+0300 [DEA/1]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:41:27.15+0300 [DEA/5]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:41:27.15+0300 [DEA/5]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:41:27.15+0300 [DEA/5]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:54:16.85+0300 [DEA/17]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:54:16.85+0300 [DEA/17]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:54:16.85+0300 [DEA/17]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
2016-07-21T21:58:50.88+0300 [DEA/39]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6c36b288-30d5-4195-b2c7-081d8f26ffdc
```

The the JAR file I used is for an IOT server for a microcontroller called blynk.

The project's github page is [here](https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server), and the JAR file itself is [here](https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server/releases/download/v0.16.4/server-0.16.4.jar).

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are seeing are normal since the jar you are uploading is not an application intended to be used on a Java Application Server such as Liberty or Tomcat. Blynk is a standalone Server.

Comment: Blynk is server application as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

For a standalone Java application, you need to specify it uses the community Java buildpack ("java_buildpack"), shown at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cfapps/byob.html . Something in the jar file may be causing it to try the Liberty Buildpack instead.